# Is it possible to assign ip address via ansible and vmware module?

Tags: ansible, ip, vsphere

I'm trying to use Ansible and Vmware module to assign an IP address to a newly created virtual machine with no network configured.
I tried vmware_guest/networks module but it requires a vlan ID and it always return vlan xxx does not exist.
Also I don't understand why it needs a vlan and the vm guest name is not enough.

This is my playbook:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Set ip for VM
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      validate_certs: No
      name: ***
      networks:
      - vlan: '***'
        type: static
        ip: 10.***.***.***
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
        gateway: 10.***.***.1
```

I tried to use vmware_shell too but it needs vmtools installed, I found a way to install them with vmware_tools_upgrade module but then I don't have the permission to run vmware_shell (I don't administer vsphere)

Maybe I should try something directly in python? I must add I have Vmware remote console access and Linux root privileges.

Comment: `Also I don't understand why it needs a vlan` <= [because the documentation specifically states it is required attribute of each network entry in the list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_module.html#parameter-networks/vlan)? (Most probably because this is required by vmware itself?)

Comment: Yes I read that, and it makes me think that that command is for creating a new virtual nic and that's not the case, I'm just trying to set the ip address, and the vlan is not needed for that.
I'm also expecting that it needs the network device name to be configured, so... I'm not sure if this is the right module for the job or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Yes*, but only during creation/deployment of a VM. While the documentation states that the VLAN ID *is* required, it is actually *not*. Just omit it, even the examples in the docs do not specify it.

Just be aware that this module cannot modify the network settings of existing VMs. It will currently only work during creation/deployment.